# Integer overflow and undefined behavior

Tags: c

There are many questions about detection of the integer overflow BEFORE the actual addition/substraction because of possible `undefined behavior`. So, my question is

Why it will produce this `undefined behavior` in the first place?

I can think of 2 causes:

1) A processor that generates exception in this case. Sure, it can be toggled off, and most probably a well written CRT will do that.

2) A processor that uses other binary representations of numbers (1's complement? base 10?). In that case the undefined behavior will manifest itself as different result (but will not crash!). Well, we could live with that.

So, why should someone avoid causing it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Mandatory link: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although *most* modern CPUs use 2's complement, and integer overflow results in predictable modulo wraparound, this is by no means universal - to keep the language sufficiently general that it can be used on the widest range of architectures it's better to specify that integer overflow is UB.

Comment: Any cpu is twos complement if your compiler simply omits generating the useless signed arithmetic opcodes and uses the unsigned ones for both signed and unsigned types. This may incur minor performance losses when making comparisons (for instance, now `x<-1` requires 2 machine-level comparisons instead of just 1), but I for one would still prefer it that way.

Comment: @R: 2's complement isn't the only issue though - e.g. some CPUs (DSPs, for example) have saturating arithmetic rather then modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Modular arithmetic is required for supporting unsigned types anyway... if your machine doesn't have it I guess you have to implement it. One approach might be using the top bit as padding and zeroing it after each operation.

Comment: It's not just different machines; it's different optimization levels within the same compiler on the same machine: http://www.kuliniewicz.org/blog/archives/2011/06/11/the-myth-of-signed-arithmetic-wraparound/

Comment: @R.. You could keep a sign bit. You don't have to use modulo arithmetic to support signed or unsigned values -- personally, I don't use modulo arithmetic when I do my own calculations and I do support unsigned calculations.

Answer (score 14):

While the historical reason signed overflow was specified as undefined behavior was probably these bogus legacy representations (ones complement/sign-magnitude) and overflow interrupts, the modern reason for it to remain undefined behavior is optimization. As J-16 SDiZ hinted at, the fact that signed overflow is undefined behavior allows the compiler to optimize out some conditionals whose algebraic truth (but not necessarily representation-level truth) are already established by a previous branch. It may also allow the compiler to algebraically simplify some expressions (especially those involving multiplication or division) in ways that could give different results than the originally-written order of evaluation if a subexpression contains an overflow, since the compiler is allowed to assume that overflow does not happen with the operands you've given it.

The other huge example of undefined behavior for the purpose of permitting optimization is the aliasing rules.

Comment: One could argue that unsigned integers should behave consistently, because why not assume that a + b >= a and a + b >= b for unsigned integers in the optimizer (similar to concluding a + b > 0 for a > 0 and b > 0 in J-16 SDiZ's example for signed integers)? In my eyes this is more of an oddity in the C spec.

Comment: @nucleon: The unsigned types are *specified as modular arithmetic* (where those algebraic equivalences of inequalities do not hold). The signed types are not. If you like to call this an oddity in C, so be it, but that's how it is and it's not really something you can change.

Answer (score 5):

The `undefined behavior` bits in the specification involve some compiler optimization. For example:

```
if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
    if ( a + b <= 0 ) {
       // this branch may be optimized out by compiler
    } else {
       // this branch will always run
    }
}
```

Modern C compilers are not that simple, it do lots of guessing and optimization.

Comment: Good point, but this only means that the C compiler won't help you detect it.

Comment: another point: while compiler would be able to detect this arithmetic condition, some bit operations would be able to fool it so that the condition won't be optimized out. Also, as suggested by      nategoose, we could just declare the sum as `volatile`.

Comment: This is not a valid use of the `volatile` keyword. If it works, it's a result of a specific implementation, not specified behavior. I.e. it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: One could achieve such optimizations without requiring integer overflow to be Undefined Behavior, if one specifies that the result of an operation yielding a value outside the range of `int` may yield any mathematical integer which would be congruent with the arithmetically-correct result, mod (2*INT_MAX+2), and that if such a value is stored to an `int` variable any read of the variable may, independently, likewise behave as any arbitrary mathematical integer in the same congruence class.  Such a rule would allow a lot of useful optimizations, and also fit a common execution model...

Comment: ...where values may be held in registers longer than `int`.  Indeed, if I had my druthers, I would define a standard term for such values "Partially-Indeterminate" and specify that an implementation could define the behavior of out-of-range signed-integer downcast as yielding a Partially-Indeterminate Value.  Otherwise types like `uint32_t` are apt to yield UB when used with machines whose int size isn't as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption 1) that this can be switched off for any given processor has been false on at least one important historical architecture, the CDC, if my memory is correct.

Comment: This one is really old. I'd rather handle these cases with `#ifdef` .

Comment: @ruslik: The question is not **how** to handle this, `#ifdef` is just one way among other to avoid UB. But you see, as you say yourself, you would handle this somehow.

Comment: backwards compatibility has its limits. In this case I'd rather prefer to write buggy, but simple code.

Comment: @ruslik: sure your mileage may vary. Certainly depends if you write your code for yourself or if you expect it to end up in a library or so. I find all this fuss that we have gone through (and still go) with 32 vs. 64 bit portability a real shame for the whole profession. And we will see this again for the next step. So, no, I for myself I try to stick to the standards.

Comment: The assumption that trapping can be switched off is correct, because, as the implementor of the compiler, you can simply choose never to generate signed-arithmetic opcodes and always use the clean/safe unsigned ones. Then you get twos complement for free at the same time.