# Difference in behaviour of unsigned and signed integer when integer overflow occurs

Tags: java, c++, c, programming-languages

Reading this article on wikipedia about [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

I dont quite understand the part why overflowing of signed integers causes undefined behaviour but overflowing of unsigned integers causes wrapping around.Why is there a difference in their behaviour?

Another questions: Do programming languages in general have any safeguards against integer overflow?

Comment: In C++ unsigned integers never overflow.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: How do you mean?

Comment: @NPE Technical terms, the wrapping behaviour of unsigned integers for out-of range results isn't overflow, technically.

Comment: Operations on unsigned integers in C++ obey the rules of arithmetic modulo 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the type. This means that there are no overflows.

Comment: Note that in Java, wrap-around behaviour is specified for all integer types.

Comment: i am wondering does it have something to do with how negative numbers are expressed in binary code??

Comment: That probably contributes too. C allows two's complement, ones' complement and sign-and-magnitude, so specifying overflow to wrap around like two's complement interpretation of unsigned integers does, isn't possible, since `-2^(WIDTH-1)` isn't representable in ones' complement and sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: C++11 3.9.1-p4:"Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." in case you were wondering to which part of the standard @R.MartinhoFernandes was referring.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandesterribly sorry (btw your avatar hat makes it a biach to copy/paste your name from your profile =P)

Comment: @WhozCraig ? `@`, `R`, tab-complete. No need to copy.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That is unfortunate phrasing, since 1/3 in 32-bit arithmetic modulo n is 2863311531, but C++ returns 0. (This is easily seen by evaluating `2863311531u*3u`. Using 32 bits, the result is 1.) It would have been better if the standard had limited this to addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

Comment: Java does not support unsigned integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer overflow and undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948479/integer-overflow-and-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

The primary rationale for the difference is the fact that C and C++ language specification allows the implementation to use one of the following three different signed integer representations

1. 1's complement
2. 2's complement
3. Signed magnitude

If the language specification mandated some specific behavior in case of signed overflow (i.e. favored one of the above representations over the other two), it would force platforms based on two non-favored representations to implement "heavy" signed integer arithmetic. It would become necessary, since the natural machine-level behavior of such platforms would not match the behavior required by the language standard. These implementation would have to constantly watch for signed overflow and adjust the results to match the standard requirements.

That would severely degrade the performance of signed integer arithmetic on platforms that use non-favored signed representations, which is, of course, completely unacceptable in such languages as C and C++, which are designed to be as close as possible to the underlying hardware when it comes to such basic operations as integer arithmetic.

The reason the behavior is *undefined* (as opposed to *unspecified") is because there are platforms out there which deliberately generate hardware exceptions in case of signed overflow during integer arithmetic. Note, that the behavior is undefined only for arithmetic operations, which are typically performed by the machine. For value conversions signed overflow does not produce undefined behavior (the behavior is actually implementation-defined).

As for unsigned types, they are represented identically on all platforms, which means that requiring consistent behavior across all platforms is not a problem. The wraparound that conceptually matches the "modulo 2^width" behavior is the natural behavior on virtually all known binary hardware platforms.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because that's the way the language is defined.  It permits development of conforming implementations more easily  on more kinds of hardware (like DSPs with saturating arithmetic, for example).
2. Depends on the language.  Some *hardware* does, and you might be able to take advantage of that in your program.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ methodology on integer overflow is to provide behaviour that is fastest on the machine you are working on, so on some machines (here assuming 16-bit signed integers):

32766 + 2 == -32768

but on some machines is:

32766 + 2 == 32767

for other machines you can have trap value or whatever the CPU will do.

Note Java has integer overflow perfectly defined, to achieve "write once, run everywhere".

As for the unsigned integers - most of their applications are bitmasks, bitfields and number manipulation (modulo operations, identifiers) - exactly the operations you don't to have them undefined.

Some of the programming languages have such safety measures, some don't:

- Python 3 auto-converts values that overflow to have type long (arbitrarily large integers).
- In C/C++ you have to check overflow conditions yourself, climits (C) and limits (C++) headers have defined maximum and minimal values for each type.
- Programming in x86 assembly - there is CF (carry flag) for unsigned and OF (overflow flag) for signed in FLAGS and EFLAGS registers to check when overflow occurs.

Many languages also have arbitrary precision type, in case you want to avoid overflow, but operations are slower, because such variables can be (in theory) as big as your memory.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you only have unsigned `int` and `long` values and their behaviour is consistent wherever you run it.  If you add 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE you bet Integer.MIN_VALUE (it wraps) and if you subtract 1 from Long.MIN_VALUE you get Long.MAX_VALUE.

So I have no idea why the behaviour of unsigned value would be undefined in other languages.

Comment: Java int and long are both signed integer types, required to behave as though they are 2's complement.

Comment: The only unsigned integer type in Java is `char` which is 16-bit.