# Signed Short (Signed Int16) Multiplication Explanation

Tags: c, types, short

Signed Short (Signed Int16) Multiplication Explanation?

```
short ss = -32768; // 0x8000 SHRT_MIN
ss *= (short) -1;
printf ("%d", (int)ss);  // Prints -32768
```

What are mechanics of how an unsigned short with a value of -32768 times -1 can be itself?  My guess is that (int)32768 ---> overflows and wraps back around to -32768 but nowhere here is asking for promotion to integer or any larger datatype.

Looking for the part of the C specification that defines this behavior.

Comment: Digging around for why it is undefined  ... "C/C++ methodology on integer overflow is to provide behaviour that is fastest on the machine you are working on, so on some machines (here assuming 16-bit signed integers):"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993047/difference-in-behaviour-of-unsigned-and-signed-integer-when-integer-overflow-occ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior here -- assuming that `int` is wider than 16 bits.

This:

```
ss *= (short) -1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
ss = ss * (short)-1;
```

Both operands of `*` are *promoted* from `short` to `int` (by the *integer promotions*), and the multiplication is done in type `int`. It yields the `int` value `32768` (again, unless `INT_MAX == 32767`, which is legal but rare in modern non-embedded systems). (C has no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int` and `unsigned int`.)

That `int` value is converted back to `short`. Unlike arithmetic operations, a conversion of an integer value to a signed integer result, when the value does not fit in the target type, yields an implementation-defined result (or raises an implementation-defined signal, but I don't think any implementations do that).

Converting `32768` to type `short` will *probably* yield `-32768`.

The behavior of signed conversion is specified in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.3p3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

The *integer promotions* are described in 6.3.1.1p2:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an **`int`**;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an **`unsigned int`**. These are called the
>   *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Comment: surely there are plenty of implementations that do raise a signal, but they're not the general purpose computers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Can you name one? Specifically, is there a C99 or C11 implementation that raises a signal on signed integer conversion (as permitted by [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.3 paragraph 3)?

Comment: Good catch on the lack of `int` overflow for 32-bit `int`.

Comment: As said, the result is subject to CPU's architecture. For more, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449/types-of-endianness

Comment: @snr: I don't think endianness would affect any of this.

Comment: @KeithThompson why sir?

Comment: @snr Why do you think endianness would affect it? If `short` is 16 bits and `int` is 32 bits, converting `32768` from `int` to `short` will *probably* yield `-32768`, regardless of endianness.