# Bit manipulation puzzles

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Does this C expression always evaluate to true?

```
((x+y)<<4) + y - x == 17*y +15*x
```

From what I can tell the arithmetic is correct, but the only thing I am unsure
about is what will happens in cases of overflow.

My understanding is that the C multiplication expressions handle overflow the 
same way as a bit shift would, but I am not sure.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Did you try running the code and purposely causing an overflow?

Comment: What are the types of these variables? Particularly, signed or unsigned?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The expression might invoke undefined behaviour in **all** operations.

Comment: in case of overflow both sides invoke undefined behavior (for signed types), or wrap around (for unsigned) and the result is still equal for both sides

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc in the signed case the expression may evaluate to false (or any other program behaviour)

Comment: @M.M yes I just said that it's equal in the unsigned case. In signed case anything can happen

Comment: @JonnyHenly while that's relevant to think about, it cannot be tested by running it - since anything could happen, it could just work, and actually that is the most likely result.

Answer (score 2):

You can run such examples through a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) to check the satisfiability of equations or formulas like you just specified.

I didn't find any X or Y which satisfied your constraints (i.e, does there exist any X or Y which produce an inequality in this equation)

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const y (_ BitVec 32))

(assert (not (= (bvsub (bvadd (bvshl (bvadd x y) #x00000004) y) x)
                (bvadd (bvmul #x00000011 y) (bvmul #x0000000f x)))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

In regards to overflow, logics over bitvectors generally provide no distinction between signed and unsigned bit-vectors as numbers. Instead, the theory of bit-vectors provides special signed versions of arithmetical operations where it makes a difference whether the bit-vector is treated as signed or unsigned. I have used the appropriate operator to the equation you've specified. Of course, you could just the results algebraically to `(x+y)<<4 == 16y + 16x` but a SMT solver handles cases like overflow which are difficult to formalize).

It doesn't matter what your instruction word size, there is no `X` or `Y` that can produce an inequality.

Comment: It is a formal "verification" of a decision procedure over bitvectors, it is an abstract model of the "world" of numerals that a C program inhabits.

Comment: I don't think that is how science & math works -- you have "absence of evidence" which does not prove anything

Comment: Without delving too deeply into Karl Popper and the philosophy of science here, the brief answer is -- Yes it is, this is a formal mathematical proof, or as close as you'll get without a kt-tactic out of a theorem prover like Coq.
If you are interested in how the decision problem applies to formal verification of problems (even simple one such is this) Donald Knuth has a whole new fascicle on it. Wikipedia has a dense but largely accessible introduction to proving statements with SAT solvers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "no" especially in case of overflow.

As you can see from answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948479/integer-overflow-and-undefined-behavior) most computers are 2-complement, but they do not have to be (and historically there have been a few one-complement computers), and overflow errors are therefore undefined behaviour.

It may work  on your computer but it is not guaranteed to work on all.

Comment: it's *complement*, not *compliment*

Comment: Signed overflows are UB regardless of whether 2's complement is in use