# putting different values in return statement of c++

Tags: c++

```
   // factorial calculator
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    long factorial (long a)
    {
      if (a > 1){

       return (a * factorial (a-1)); }//function calling itsself
     else
     return 0;
   }

    main ()
    {
     long number = 2;
      cout << number << "! = " << factorial (number);

    }
```

i am begginer learning objects and classes. i get some code from my context but its getting some error. 
       how return statement is working when its value is 0 out put becomes 0 when it is return 1 output is 2. when it is return 3 output is 6 similar for 4 is 8.

Comment: Please trace the recursion on paper (or with your debugger) for `factorial(2)`, for example, and you'll see your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a calculator to compute factorial

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Factorial(int long long a) {
    int long long Ans = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x <= a; x++) {
        Ans *= x;
    }

    return Ans;
}

int main() {

    int Input;
    cin >> Input;   

    if (Input > 0) {
        cout << Factorial(Input);
    }
}
```

Calling a function from within itself is generally considered bad practice, so avoid it. Use `long long` if you need larger numbers. Also, try to provide more information about your question.

Comment: Ah yes, I fixed that

Comment: And just to be even more pedantic, `Factorial((long long) INT_MAX + 1)` will never terminate, and invokes [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3948518/1270789).