# Store an int in a char buffer in C and then retrieve the same

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am writing a socket client-server application where the server needs to send a large buffer to a client and all buffers should be processed separately, so I want to put the buffer length in the buffer so that the client can read the length of data from the buffer and process accordingly.

To put the length value I need to divide an integer value in one byte each and store it in a buffer to be sent over the socket. I am able to break the integer into four parts, but at the time of joining I am not able to retrieve the correct value. To demonstrate my problem I have written a sample program where I am dividing int into four char variables and then join it back in another integer. The goal is that after joining I should get the same result.

Here is my small program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int inVal = 0, outVal =0;
    char buf[5] = {0};

    inVal = 67502978;

    printf ("inVal: %d\n", inVal);

    buf[0] = inVal & 0xff;
    buf[1] = (inVal >> 8) & 0xff;
    buf[2] = (inVal >> 16) & 0xff;
    buf[3] = (inVal >> 24) & 0xff;

    outVal = buf[3];
    outVal = outVal << 8;
    outVal |= buf[2];
    outVal = outVal << 8;
    outVal |= buf[1];
    outVal = outVal << 8;
    outVal |= buf[0];

    printf ("outVal: %d\n",outVal);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

inVal: 67502978
outVal: -126

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer overflow and undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948479/integer-overflow-and-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Is it possible that your architecture has 64 bit `int`s?

Answer (score 19):

One problem is that you are using bit-wise operators on signed numbers. This is always a bad idea and almost always incorrect. Please note that `char` has implementation-defined signedness, unlike `int` which is always signed.

Therefore you should replace `int` with `uint32_t` and `char` with `uint8_t`. With such unsigned types you eliminate the possibility of using bit shifts on negative numbers, which would be a bug. Similarly, if you shift data into the sign bits of a signed number, you *will* get bugs.

And needless to say, the code will not work if integers are not 4 bytes large.

Comment: @LPs My thinking too. The general algorithmic idea is, if I'm not mistaken, endianness-independent because the bit shift operator is endianness-ignorant (or -invariant, or whatever: left shift is always multiplying, right-shift dividing). This is the way to go in order to implement ntohl and friends without looking at the architecture's endianness.

Comment: I don't understand _Should you use bit shifts on a number that is negative, you might get bugs._. How can he have negative numbers if he changes the types to `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`?

Comment: @gurka The point is to use unsigned types of specified width to prevent such bugs. Since you misunderstood, the answer is apparently not optimally worded.

Comment: Unfortunately, C is a very inconsistent and irrational language. What's not mentioned here is that even if you use `uint8_t`, you could end up with negative numbers, because of the integer promotion rules in C. For example `~uint8 << n` always invokes undefined behavior, unlike `~uint32 << n` which is always perfectly fine (on 32 bit sys).  This is because the former is equivalent to `~(int)uint8 << n`. The key to avoiding these subtle but disastrous bugs is to learn about the various forms of implicit type promotion in C.

Answer (score 12):

Your method has potential implementation defined behavior as well as undefined behavior:

- storing values into the array of type `char` beyond the range of type `char` has implementation defined behavior: `buf[0] = inVal & 0xff;` and the next 3 statements (`inVal & 0xff` might be larger than `CHAR_MAX` if `char` type is signed by default).
- left shifting negative values invokes undefined behavior: if any of the 3 first bytes in the array becomes negative as the implementation defined result of storing a value larger than `CHAR_MAX` into it, the resulting `outVal` becomes negative, left shifting it is undefined.

In your specific example, your architecture uses 2's complement representation for negative values and the type `char` is signed. The value stored into `buf[0]` is `67502978 & 0xff = 130`, becomes `-126`. The last statement `outVal |= buf[0];` sets bits 7 through 31 of `outVal` and the result is `-126`.

You can avoid these issues by using an array of `unsigned char` and values of type `unsigned int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int inVal = 0, outVal = 0;
    unsigned char buf[4] = { 0 };

    inVal = 67502978;

    printf("inVal: %u\n", inVal);

    buf[0] = inVal & 0xff;
    buf[1] = (inVal >> 8) & 0xff;
    buf[2] = (inVal >> 16) & 0xff;
    buf[3] = (inVal >> 24) & 0xff;

    outVal = buf[3];
    outVal <<= 8;
    outVal |= buf[2];
    outVal <<= 8;
    outVal |= buf[1];
    outVal <<= 8;
    outVal |= buf[0];

    printf("outVal: %u\n", outVal);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above code still assumes 32-bit ints.

Comment: Actually, it *doesn't* assume 8-bit bytes.  It assumes that unsigned char can hold *at least* 8 bits (which the standard guarantees).  (For the calculation of outval it also assumes that buf only contains valid values in the range 0..255.)

Comment: The program does *not* have undefined behavior. It also does not have implementation defined behavior since all values stored in the chars are masked by `0xff` and thus representable in a `char` which is guaranteed to have at least 8 bits.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: it *does* have implementation defined behavior in C: **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers:** *When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, ...
3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* The values masked by `0xff` may exceed the range of type `char`, and 130 indeed does.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: The program does not invoke undefined behavior for the specific value `inVal = 67502978`, but the method used does for many other values, such as `inVal = 32768`.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, use std types with fixed widths `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` for example. As an embedded coder I only ever use these types (*never* just `int` for example) as I've learned that assumption will bite you eventually.

Answer (score 6):

While bit shifts of signed values *can* be a problem, this is not the case here (all left hand values are positive, and all results are within the range of a 32 bit unsigned int).

The problematic expression with somewhat unintuitive semantics is the last bitwise OR:

```
outVal |= buf[0];
```

`buf[0]` is a (on your and my architecture) signed char with the value -126, simply because the most significant bit in the least significant byte of 67502978 is set. In C all operands in an arithmetic expression are subject to the arithmetic conversions. Specifically, they undergo *integer promotion* which states: "If an int can represent all values of the original type [...], the value is converted to an int". Accordingly, the signed character `buf[0]` is converted to a (signed) `int`, *preserving its value of  -126.* A negative signed int has the sign bit set. ORing that with another signed int sets the result's sign bit as well, making that value negative. That is exactly what we are seeing.

Making the bytes `unsigned char`s fixes the issue because the value of the temporary integer to which the unsigned char is converted is then a simple 8 bit value of 130.

Answer (score 4):

Use `unsigned char buf[5] = {0};` and `unsigned int` for `inVal` and `outVal`, and it should work.

When using signed integral types, there arise two sorts of problems:

First, if `buf[3]` is negative, then due to `outVal = buf[3]` variable `outVal` becomes negative; consequent bit shift operators on `outVal` are then undefined behaviour [cppreference.com concerning bit shift operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> For signed and positive a, the value of a << b is a * 2b  if it is
>   representable the return type, otherwise the behavior is
>   undefined. (until C++14), the value of a << b is a * 2b  if it is
>   representable in the unsigned version of the return type (which is
>   then converted to signed: this makes it legal to create INT_MIN as
>   1<<31), otherwise the behavior is undefined. (since C++14)
>
> **For negative a, the behavior of a << b is undefined.**

Note that with OP's `inVal = 67502978` this does not occur, since `buf[3]=4`; But for other `inVal`s it may occur and then may bring problems due to "undefined behaviour".

The second problem is that with operation `outVal |= buf[0]` with `buf[0]=-126`, the value `(char)-126`, which in binary format is `10000010`, is converted to `(int)-126`, which in binary format is `11111111111111111111111110000010` before operator `|=` is applied, and this then will fill up `outVal` with a lot of `1`-bits. The reason for conversion is defined at [conversion rules for arithmetic operations (cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> If both operands are signed or both are unsigned, the operand with
>   lesser conversion rank is converted to the operand with the greater
>   integer conversion rank

So the problem in OP's case is actually not because of any undefined behaviour, but because of having character `buf[3]` being a negative value, which is converted to `int` before `|=` operation.

Note, however, that if either `buf[2]` or `buf[1]` had been negative, this would have made `outVal` negative and would have lead to undefined behaviour on subsequent shift operations, too.

Comment: Where do you see an overflowing integer operation? All shifts are done on (afaics none-overflowing) `int`s.

Comment: This is not an integer overflow, it is a direct manipulation of the sign bits. It is undefined behavior per C11 6.5.7/4: "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions;" /--/ "If E1 has a signed
type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Lundin: You are right, since there is a more specific specification of bit shift's behaviour. I actually thought it would also violate the more general overflow rule, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Lundin All shits are well defined, cf. my comment to Saurav's post. Stephan: The shifts are not the issue here.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - ignore my comment.  It was wrong.

Comment: `buf[3]` is not negative; it is 4 for a 32 bit little endian. `outval` is never negative when shifted. Your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider In the case where any byte from the original int has a value larger than 127 and `char` is a signed type, the value will get converted to a signed type in some implementation-defined way. The result may be a negative number. And then when the `char` gets used in an expression, it gets promoted to `int`, the sign is preserved, and the code might invoke undefined behavior. In this specific case, 67502978 -> 0x04060382. `buf[0]` will contain raw value 0x82, which is possibly a negative number. Which will turn `outVal` negative too.

Comment: So the shifts are not a problem in this very specific case only by pure luck, since the ls byte was never shifted. Had any other byte gotten a value over 127 there would have been undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin I understand that (admittedly after the discussion with chqrlie elsewhere). My "never negative" referred to the program as presented by the OP. Stephan's wrapping up his answer  "So the main issue is [the bit shift]" is not correct, because the bit shift as presented is not an issue. Sure, that is coincidental  and not portably safe, but I think there is some value in understanding where the unexpected negative value comes from, and exactly *why* using unsigned chars helps (not because it shifts correctly).

Comment: If OP cares about the highest bit in in/out value, I would also recommend using "unsigned int" for inVal and outVal

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider: you are right, the actual problem with OP's `intVal` arises not due to undefined behaviour of shift operators on negative numbers (although this problem will potentially arise for other `intVal`s). Thanks for pointing this out in a consequent manner. Adapted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

C++ standard N3936 quotes about shift operators:

> > The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated
> >     bits are zero-filled.
>
> If `E1` has an **unsigned type**,
>
> > the value of the result is `E1 × 2^E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> >     representable in the result type.
>
> Otherwise, if `E1` has a **signed type** and non-negative value,
>
> > and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the
> >     corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value,
> >     converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the
> >     behavior is *undefined*.

So, to avoid `undefined` behaviour, it is recommended to use `unsigned` data types, and ensure the `64-bits` length of data type.

Comment: Hm. I see the following values for `outval` before each shift: (32 bit little endian ints): 4; 1030; 263680. None of them are negative, and the results are all within range, so they are all well defined. The value after the last shift is 67502848. It's the last OR that creates the negative value.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a terrible idea but I'll post it here for interest - you can use a [union](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/):

```
union my_data
{
    uint32_t one_int;

    struct
    {
        uint8_t  byte3;
        uint8_t  byte2;
        uint8_t  byte1;
        uint8_t  byte0;
    }bytes;
};


// Your original code modified to use union my_data
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    union my_data data;
    uint32_t inVal = 0, outVal = 0;
    uint8_t buf[4] = {0};

    inVal = 67502978;

    printf("inVal: %u\n", inVal);

    data.one_int = inVal;

    // Populate bytes into buff    
    buf[3] = data.bytes.byte3;
    buf[2] = data.bytes.byte2;
    buf[1] = data.bytes.byte1;
    buf[0] = data.bytes.byte0;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this would also work, can't see why not:

```
union my_data
{
    uint32_t one_int;
    uint8_t  bytes[4];
};
```

Comment: +1 This is the best way of doing this. It is both non-portable, and undefined behaviour, **but so is anything assuming that assumes you can translate between an `int` and four `chars`**. I would combine with Jim D.'s answer to ensure endian-correctness, however.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you've made an error in your code beginning with `outVal = data.bytes.byte3`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jack, well spotted. I've updated code now to reflect the task at hand (getting bytes into `buf` from `inVal`).

Comment: That's precisely **not** what unions are for. Anyway, you forgot `#pragma pack 1`. Alternatively, `uint8_t [4]` is much safer than 4 independent fields because it avoids the packing issue.

Comment: I did say it's probably a terrible idea, so I was right.

Answer (score 2):

Because of endian differences between architectures, it is best practice to convert numeric values to `network order`, which is big-endian.  On receipt, they can then be converted to the native host order.  We can do this in a portable way by using `htonl()` (host to network "long" = uint32_t), and convert to host order on receipt with `ntohl()`.  Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  uint32_t inval = 67502978, outval, backinval;

  outval = htonl(inval);
  printf("outval: %d\n", outval);
  backinval = ntohl(outval);
  printf("backinval: %d\n", backinval);
  return 0;
}
```

This gives the following result on my 64 bit x86 which is little endian:

```
$ gcc -Wall example.c
$ ./a.out
outval: -2113731068
backinval: 67502978
$
```

Comment: While your remark raises an important point for the binary exchange of values, it does not explain the OP's problem. Using a different byte order would not solve the problem either.

Comment: While @chqrlie has a point, +1 for the mandatory pointer to `htonl` and friends. I suspect that many spontaneous resets of the various embedded systems in my household could be avoided if people stopped attempts at re-implementing `htonl` etc. Disseminating best practice is a service to mankind. Especially because the attempts are usually not a sign of competence and thus bound to fail.

Comment: I *really* *really* don't like the interface of htonl et al.  htonl should return an array of octets - not an int (I can imagine a platform where htonl of a valid integer ends up returning a trap value).

Comment: @MartinBonner I cannot.  If there is padding or such which should have defined values (for example, 0), `htonl` should make damn sure that it conforms for that architecture; any amateurish DIY attempt would be even more failure-prone in such thorny environment.

Comment: A little endian sign and magnitude or ones-complement machine where negative zero is a trap.  A 0x00000080 would end up as a big-endian 0x80000000 which is the trap value.

Comment: If htonl returned { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80 } there wouldn't be a problem.  (Well, apart from the fact that returning an array is tricky.)  The point is that "network values" should just be sequences of octets.  Trying to pass them around as anything else is conceptually wrong.

Comment: _I suspect that many spontaneous resets of the various embedded systems in my household could be avoided if people stopped attempts at re-implementing htonl etc._ ...well many of embedded devices uses very low price mcu and toolchains or SDK (if you are lucky) of vendor are very poor. htonl and friends are a mirage...

Comment: @MartinBonner  Although it is called `htonl()` it doesn't return an int, it returns a uint32_t.  I would expect that `0x80000000` is a valid unsigned 32 bit integer on all architectures.

Comment: @MartinBonner I get your point (do not interpret network bytes as natively typed values). I think it is valid.

Comment: uint32_t - Aah!  I think that may be recent (within the last 20 years).  Yes, that makes it much safer (but my conceptual argument still stands).